# Посмотреть исходящий трафик Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails

Устанавливал первый раз приложение Rails на VDS Ubuntu 14.04 via Passenger. Сервер взломали на вторые сутки, о чем узнал из письма хостинг-провайдера, где говорилось, что с моего IP DDoS-ят. Поскольку приложение было еще не очень готово просто все снес. Сейчас установил приложение повторно и, похоже, история повторяется. В панели управления VDS вижу исходящий траффик 5 Гб... Явно не мой. Где смотреть содержание траффика? И что его генерит? Есть какой-то левый IP в sysloge:

```
Jan 17 22:59:01 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[7891]: connect from unknown[193.189.117.154]
Jan 17 22:59:01 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[7891]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.189.117.154]
Jan 17 22:59:01 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[7891]: disconnect from unknown[193.189.117.154]  

Jan 17 11:47:54 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[10106]: connect from unknown[193.189.117.154]
Jan 17 11:47:54 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[10106]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[193.189.117.154]
Jan 17 11:47:54 vm16590 postfix/smtpd[10106]: disconnect from unknown[193.189.117.154]
Jan 17 11:48:58 vm16590 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="328" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan 17 11:49:08 vm16590 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="374" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 17 11:49:08 vm16590 rsyslogd-3003: invalid or yet-unknown config file command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' - have you forgotten to load a module? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3003 ]
Jan 17 11:49:08 vm16590 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Jan 17 11:49:08 vm16590 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Jan 17 11:49:08 vm16590 rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 cron[438]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/chargen [file=/etc/xinetd.conf] [line=14]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/daytime [file=/etc/xinetd.d/daytime] [line=28]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/discard [file=/etc/xinetd.d/discard] [line=26]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/echo [file=/etc/xinetd.d/echo] [line=25]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/time [file=/etc/xinetd.d/time] [line=26]
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing chargen
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing chargen
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing daytime
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing daytime
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing discard
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing discard
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing echo
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing echo
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing time
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: removing time
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: xinetd Version 2.3.15 started with libwrap loadavg options compiled in.
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 xinetd[464]: Started working: 0 available services
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 cron[479]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 cron[479]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jan 17 11:49:09 vm16590 postfix/master[583]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
```

Comment: для начала - tcpdump

Comment: @AntonioK это же в реальном времени? Сейчас все спокойно. Последний всплеск был в 1.00 по МСК. Добавлю кусок syslog около этого времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удобнее всего записывать трафик в файл, затем скачать этот файл и просмотреть его локально, например, с помощью gui-программы *wireshark* (из одноимённого пакета).

записывать же можно так (после установки пакета *tshark*):

```
$ sudo tshark -w /путь/к/файлу/в/который/записывать
```

конечно, имеет смысл **не** записывать пакеты с *вашим* ip-адресом, с которого вы подключаетесь к серверу:

```
$ sudo tshark -w /путь/к/файлу -f "not host ваш.ip.адр.ес"
```

для прекращения записи надо лишь остановить процесс. например, нажав <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>.

---

**дополнение о просмотре**

просматривать записанный (в бинарном виде) трафик можно не только с помощью gui-программы *wireshark*, но и с помощью той же самой программы *tshark*:

```
$ tshark -r /путь/к/файлу/куда/велась/запись
```

Comment: Спасибо, а есть способ запуска в качестве сервиса?

Comment: @nobilik, используйте screen или tmux.

Comment: Сейчас у меня летит исходящий траффик. Но посмотреть не получается, потому как лог вот так выглядит: `^D^@3�^@^@^@^@^A^C^C^Gl^@^@^@^E^@^@^@l^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�)^E^@둪�^A^@^\^@Counters provided by dumpcap^B^@^H^@�)^E^@"�a�^C^@^H^@�)^E^@$���^D^@^H^@瑪^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^E^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@l^@^@^@` Что я неправильно делаю?

Comment: @nobilik, я дополнил ответ.